# Resizing specific faces of a 3D mesh

Tags: modeling

I have this column:

[image]

But the top and the bottom parts have different size between the curved figure and the final edge of the mesh.

Top

[image]

Bottom

[image]

How can I adjust this and have equal size at each side?

Comment: Grab the vertex, move them up/down, until the reach the column top or bottom, use snapping to get a precise translation. Then move them up/down again but use numeric values to get an absolute value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try cutting the model in half, then delete the bottom part. Then use Mirror modifier. Apply it, and if you don't need the cut at the center, just select it by loop select and press `X` + dissolve. This is, of course, the case when both sides should be similar. It's a column, so I think they should. Let me know if it's not the case - I will update my answer.